# How to read Key - value pair from property file using annotations

Tags: java, spring

How to read this (fixedRate = 12000) 12000 form property file in Spring.

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate=120000)
public void tlogZipping() throws MposWSException {
    LOGGER.info("Started tlog Zipping Job............. {}" + new Date());
    try {
        //......................
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("FAIL TO CREATE RECEIPT ZIP FILE: {}",e);
        throw new MposWSException(MposWSErrorCodes.FAIL_TO_CREATE_RECEIPT_ZIP_FILE, e);
    }
    LOGGER.info("Stopped tlog Zipping Job.............");
}
```

Comment: there is no such file what could i see to your code ?? @Dipesh

Comment: My file name is MyProperty.properties and it contains : TLOG_ZIPPING_TIME_INTERVEL_IN_MINUTES=1200000

Comment: is this a annotated key like `@TLOG_ZIPPING_TIME_INTERVEL_IN_MINUTES` or simple key like `TLOG_ZIPPING_TIME_INTERVEL_IN_MINUTES`

Comment: I just want o read "120000" from property filee. TLOG_ZIPPING_TIME_INTERVEL_IN_MINUTES is key and 120000 value in property file.

Comment: if number of properties are not too much then you can use any `xml` file as a properties file. It is a much better concept that can be used.

Comment: which version of spring are you using ? if it is 3.2.2+ it supports fixedRate to take string values ... and you can use property placeholder from property file

Comment: Hi Ali, i am  using springframework 4.1.0. It is very good for me if i replace that value with string . please give me any example so i can refer it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your properties file to the folder where your `classes` are exists.
and then try this code.

```
 @PropertySource("classpath:config.properties") //set your Properties file source.
public class YourClass{

    //1.2.3.4
    @Value("${TLOG_ZIPPING_TIME_INTERVEL_IN_MINUTES }") //read your Property Key
    private String IntervalTimeInMin;  //Store in this Variable.

    //hello
    @Value("${anotherProperty}")  //readd another Property Key
    private String anotherProperty; //Store in this Variable.
```

For more assistence you can refer this [Link Here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertysources-example/)

Comment: Thanks Vikrant but if it is good we can change @Scheduled(fixedRate=120000) this "120000" with any integer value in class . So i can initialize this int value in constructor.